# Google Assistant SDK - Actions get information from SQL Server

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

I'm trying to make my own Google Assistant Actions.

I would like to ask a question. SQL Server is the data source for this. Google Assistant is searching my SQL Server for results. When it finds the result, it reads out the result. Would this be possible? Where can I search or read for more information about how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/assistant) broadly. Specifically, you're looking to build a [conversational action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational) where the user can ask questions that match [Intents](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/intents) that you provide to the Assistant to match. When an Intent is matched, the information is passed to your code, which is running as a [webhook](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhooks), to generate a [response](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts).

Your webhook can do pretty much whatever you want, as long as you do it quickly enough (in about 5 seconds) and return a response. This can include database queries or any other processing or business logic necessary. Details about doing so for SQL Server are out of the scope for this particular question - but it should be very similar to doing SQL Server queries from any other server you're running.

Comment: As you're developing, if you have additional issues, ask it as a new SO question. Be sure to tag them with "actions-on-google", and provide as much detail, include code, screen shots, and errors, as you can.

Comment: Thx you. I made a new question maybe youre familiar with ASP.NET and also can help me